# Auto Increment _Id in Spring MongoRepository

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, jakarta-ee, spring-mongo

Is there a way to mimic the @GeneratedValue in [MongoRepository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/MongoRepository.html)?

I would like to auto increment the _id

Comment: there is no official way to have auto-generated integer id in mongoDB but you can use `findAndModify` to mimic the behaviour. See link http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/

Answer (score 0):

Not reliably, particularly since MongoDB doesn't support transactions. The recommended approach is to use a MongoDB `ObjectID`.